# filter by color after adding conditional formatting

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, filter, json-formatting, column-formatting

If you create conditional formatting on a column in SharePoint list that is dynamic, say for example all dates before today are red, today is green and dates after today are amber, is there a way to then filter using these colors?

Comment: Hi @Jennifer, does my answer below help you in any way? If yes, please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily. It also removes this question from "Unanswered questions" list.

Answer (score 0):

Column formatting only customize how fields in SharePoint lists and libraries are displayed, it does not store any value/information in list.

So, you **cannot** filter the list items based on colors/values added using conditional JSON formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Ganesh Sanap. Conditional JSON formatting cannot be used to filter. As a workaround, you could create a calculated column to show corresponding color in the JSON formatting. Then use calculated column to filter.

===================================

If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.

Comment: I’m checking how the things are going on about this issue. Whether the answer helps you? If there is any problem with this issue, feel free to let me know.